# 圧縮ファイルを解凍せずに中身を検索したい。

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

初投稿です。知識不足申し訳ございません。
Windows10環境にて圧縮ファイル(Zip等)の中身から判断して時間を掛けずに
指定のフォルダに振り分けてくれるバッチファイルもしくはアプリを作りたいと思っています。
そこで質問なのですがエクスプローラの検索の設定にある
「圧縮されたファイル(Zip、CAB...)を含める」のような
ことができるコマンドやそれができる方法が知りたいです。
Linux,Unixは持っておらず、Windowsで実装したいと思っています。
インターネットで調べただけですが見つからず、どうやって皆さんは知ったのかも知りたいです。

以上よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 検索対象は「ファイル名だけ」ですか？それとも「ファイルの中身も」でしょうか？

Comment: 圧縮ファイルの中のファイル名だけです。

Comment: ファイル名だけと想定しています

Comment: 今回は1件目の回答を参考に作っていくのですが手段を増やす目的で参考までにどんな方法でもいいので(～言語で～を使って同じようなことをした等)検索できる方法があれば教えてほしいです。

Answer (score 1):

unzipコマンドを使用すると圧縮されているファイルリストが取得できます。

windows版のunzipコマンドは以下からダウンロードできます。
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm

コマンドプロンプトを起動しunzipコマンドを以下のようなオプションで実行してみてください。
unzip -l xxx.zip

どのようにこの情報にたどり着いたか。ですが、
「zip ファイルリスト」を検索キーワードにgoogle検索すれば出てきます。

Comment: なるほどWindows環境でLinuxコマンドを使えるようにするということですね

Answer (score 1):

[7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)のコマンドライン版、`7z.exe`で書庫(Zip)ファイルを解凍せずに中身を確認できます。
ファイル一覧を表示するスイッチ`l`と、検索したいパターン(以下の例では`*.txt`)を指定します。

```
> 7z l -ir!*.txt archive.zip
```

Comment: 7-Zipを入れてあればコマンドで中身を確認できたのですね。この圧縮、解凍ソフトを使っていましたが盲点でした。